# Recalculating lux from EV

Tags: visible-light, units, unit-conversion

I have to calculate amount of light from IR emmiter. The only equipement, that I can use is Sekonic Light Meter like this one: http://www.ebay.com/bhp/sekonic-l-358

The problem is that i need to have the light level in lux, but the metter gives me the values in EV. 
Could anybody tell me how could I recalculate those results: 11,6EV 11,4EV 11,1EV 10,4EV 9,3EV

Answer (score 0):

EV stands for [exposure value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value). The [equation to convert EV to lux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value#EV_as_a_measure_of_luminance_and_illuminance) is:

$$ L = 2.5 \times 2^{EV} $$

Since you're using a Sekonic meter note that Sekonic [provide a conversion chart here](http://www.sekonic.com/support/evluxfootcandleconversionchart.aspx).